# Is there any advantage in saving weight?

Tags: bomber-crew

Is there any advantage to having my bomber weight below it's maximum capacity?

Eg does the plane fly faster or use less fuel when the weight is lower?

Answer (score 2):

**When you are below your maximum weight capacity, your plane will fly faster.** I am not 100% sure about using less fuel or anything else though. However, I do recommend that you try to reach your maximum weight capacity as the benefits of increased armour, damage, fuel, and other such things are much more important than just flying a bit faster.